# Spree deface, submit button add class

Tags: themes, spree, deface

How to select a search submit button to apply class to it using deface?

tried this:

```
set_attributes 'form.input[type="submit"]'
attributes :class => 'saerchbox_submit'
```

bot does not seem to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some elements on the **Deface::Override** block.

```
:set_attributes => 'input[type="submit"]',
:attributes => {:class => 'searchbox_submit'})
```

That should work fine.

I also recommend you to check out the [Deface README](https://github.com/spree/deface/blob/master/README.markdown), it's way better than the Spree one for Deface use and have a lot of examples.